# problem executing an SQL command in Python with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to run an sql commands with sqlalchemy in python, all the queries I'm trying to do are running successfully besides one, and the error I get is about syntax. when I take the code the an sql environment it works successfully. Here is the code I'm trying to run (this part is working!):

```
con.execute("USE covid19_korea")
con.execute("SET @currdate := (select min(confirmed_date) from facts)")
con.execute("SET @enddate :=  (select DATE_ADD((select max(confirmed_date) from facts), INTERVAL 14 DAY))")
```

From this part it doesn't work:

```
query = """
        delimiter $$
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BuildDate$$
        CREATE PROCEDURE BuildDate()
            BEGIN
                 WHILE @currdate < @enddate DO
                    INSERT INTO Dimension_Date (date, day, month, year, day_name)
                    VALUES (
                             @currdate, DAY(@currdate), MONTH(@currdate), YEAR(@currdate), DAYNAME(@currdate)
                            );
                    SET @currdate:= DATE_ADD(@currdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
                END WHILE;

            END$$
        CALL BuildDate();"""

con.execute(query)
```

and here is the error I get:

```
ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, **"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter $$\n        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BuildDate$$\n        CREATE PROCEDU' at line 1")**
[SQL: 
        delimiter $$
        DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BuildDate$$
        CREATE PROCEDURE BuildDate()
            BEGIN
                 WHILE @currdate < @enddate DO
                    INSERT INTO Dimension_Date (date, day, month, year, day_name)
                    VALUES (
                             @currdate, DAY(@currdate), MONTH(@currdate), YEAR(@currdate), DAYNAME(@currdate)
                            );
                    SET @currdate:= DATE_ADD(@currdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
                END WHILE;

            END$$
        CALL BuildDate();]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Comment: From the top of my head `delimiter <something>` is a mysql command line client command, not an actual SQL command.

Comment: Dropping off a reference that might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455547/delimiter-creating-a-trigger-in-sqlalchemy. As @Ilja Everilä points out, the delimiters is probably the issue here.

Comment: I also thought that the delimiter is the issue but didnt know how to handle with it :(

Comment: After getting rid of `delimiter $$`, send the DROP, CREATE, and CALL statements separately using `conn.execute()`. You may have to do some hand holding in case of calling the stored procedure, since SQLAlchemy's autocommit cannot know that it is a data changing operation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51561894/calling-stored-function-or-procedure-wont-insert-and-persist-changes

Comment: thank you!!! it now does not crash anymore, but from some reason it doesnt do the CALL statement.. thats how i seperated it:

con.execute("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS BuildDate")

query = """CREATE PROCEDURE BuildDate() .... """
con.execute(query)
con.execute("CALL BuildDate()")

but when i look at the table in the db its empty, the function is not really called.

Comment: See my previous comment; it most likely does execute your CALL, but it does not commit the changes. SQLAlchemy's autocommit—if you're using it—relies on identifying statements that make changes, but it cannot identify a call to a stored procedure as such.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thank you very much :)